# How would I go about triple-booting (Windows/Arch/Ubuntu)? (also quad-booting later)

Tags: linux, windows, dual-boot

I am going to completely change the way my drives are set up soon, and I want to triple-boot (mostly because easier development).

My current drives are a 240GB SSD and 1TB HDD, however I will likely add a 480GB SSD and 2TB HDD to that after Christmas.

I want operating systems to be stored on the future 480 drive (triple booting doesn't make sense on a 240). I am planning to use Windows 10 (streaming/gaming), Arch (experimentation with config files), and Ubuntu for daily programming and Linux-based tasks.

Before you ask, no, VMs are not an option for me, as I don't have a super powerful machine. I would also like the option to quad-boot in the future, as I have a planned YouTube series that would require me to switch said 4th operating system daily.

How would I go about this?

Comment: You don't need a super powerful machine to support a couple (or more) VMs for playing around with config files and doing programming. And if you, as you say, want to switch out one of the operating systems _daily_, then doing it as a quad-boot machine instead of in a VM is going to be a _real pain_ (especially if you are wanting to set up video capture each time, something that comes almost for free with a VM).

Comment: Just be sure to install all systems in same boot mode, or all UEFI/gpt or all BIOS/MBR. Although Ubuntu can use MBR with UEFI, not recommended. Windows requires gpt for UEFI boot. I would use smaller / (root) or system partition(s) and have a larger shared data partition. Perhaps some data in NTFS for use with Windows (fast start up off) and some ext4 for Linux only. I use 25 GB for / and have one system with Windows in 100GB (was 50 but upgrade from 8 to 10 needed lots of space) with two Linux installs. I do not use Windows much so no real data in it.

Answer (score 0):

Please, let me at least touch the VM-topic.

You don't provide a sufficient rationale for triple-/quad-boot IMHO. On the contrary what you say directly points towards virtualization as it would make the described tasks much easier.

There is no need to have a *super-powerful machine*, just any machine with Intel VT-x or AMD-V.

You may check this even as a normal user with:

- Intel:

  ```
  grep vmx /proc/cpuinfo
  ```

  resp.
- AMD:

  ```
  grep svm /proc/cpuinfo
  ```

Make sure it is enabled in your UEFI / BIOS if not found in your CPU flags.

---

In **2006**, both Intel ([VT-x](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X86_virtualization#Intel_virtualization_(VT-x))) and AMD ([AMD-V](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X86_virtualization#AMD_virtualization_(AMD-V))) introduced limited hardware virtualization support.  Source: [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X86_virtualization).

Comment: I understand. However, I still feel more comfortable with running stuff on bare metal, and when it comes to talking with my parents, they don't want me to touch virtualization. It's honestly a matter of preference for me, and you could've said this in a comment instead of an answer.

Comment: @ProgrammerPlays Alright. I do not have experience with booting multiple systems from **the same drive** myself, yet I do use dual-boot from separate drives, so answering this indirectly as I did, was the only way my expertise allows. I'm confident someone else will step in and just give you the needed information. This answer, I believe, holds an alternate approach, might be valuable to future readers, so I'll keep it in here. Cheers!